# Add-on for Appointments scheduler suggestions?

Tags: events

Looking for an appointments scheduler add-on for EE. Looked at rEEservartion but not quite the right fit. Basically what we need is the following:

A system enabling appointments to be scheduled for a one-off 2-day event with set times of half an hour from 10 - 5.

Signed-up members - say 10 in total - form a 'pool' which need to schedule meetings with each other. Each member can click to 'book' (no payment involved) a half hour slot with another member of the pool and set this to unavailable in both their own scheduler and the booked one.

So, Mr Smith clicks on "10-10.30 AM" on Mr Jones Scheduler and the add-on blocks out this slot on both Smith and Jones' schedule. It also sends an email to both members notifying them.

Conversely it should also be possible to cancel this (by Smith or Jones) and free the slot again.

Is there any add-on for this? Does not need to hook up with any payment system...purely internal. I think it is also possible to do through channels and Zoo Visitor maybe and by-pass the Add-on.

Anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably no easy add-on for scheduling as you describe it.

As you mention, this scheduling app would be possible with regular channels, channel:form and a bit of javascript. When adding a new booking, the system would need to check for entries (availability) for both members and then (ajax) submit a channel:form. To cancel a booking, you'ld need to set the status to cancelled (deleting entries with channel:form/safecracker is not possible, as far as i know).